# Service to Service Authorization in micro services

Tags: security, architecture, authorization, microservices

I have a scenario where there are multiple micro services which are authenticated through SSO. But, I want to have a layer on these services where a REST call from a particular service should not be processed by the common services .

Let's say there are service A,service B and service C which are authenticated through SSO. But I want to prevent service A from making any calls to service B. can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Perhaps you don't need to implement it on your service. IP tables or load balancers can do that.

Comment: @Hippoom thanks for the comment. I am thinkinng of more lake api gatewat and service register thing which can help me with tht.